# Why is std::map index off by one?

Tags: c++11

I am trying to get the index of the key in the map. I use distance
for this. Why is the result always one off? I was expecting "ale" 
index to be 2 but the answer is 1.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

  std::map<std::string, int> my_map;

  my_map.insert(std::make_pair("apple", 0));
  my_map.insert(std::make_pair("a", 0));
  my_map.insert(std::make_pair("ale", 0));
  my_map.insert(std::make_pair("aple", 0));
  my_map.insert(std::make_pair("aplle", 0));

  std::cout << "map size = " << my_map.size() << std::endl;
  int index  = distance(my_map.begin(), my_map.find("ale"));
  std::cout << "index = " << index << std::endl;

  index  = distance(my_map.begin(), my_map.find("a"));
  std::cout << "index = " << index << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why did you expect a 2 index for "ale"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print the keys of the `map` in the order in which they are stored in the map. Then, the return value of `std::distance` will make sense.

```
for ( auto& item : my_map )
{
   std::cout << item.first << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
a ale aple aplle apple
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` (an *associative* container) does not maintain elements in 'insert order` like `std::vector` (a *sequence* container). It maintains them in whatever sorted order makes map lookup efficient.

Comment: More accurately, it returns iterators to them them in the sorted order. The efficiency,of the internal representation is irrelevant.